# Deja Dup Ubuntu One plugin

Tags: ubuntu-one, deja-dup

I know this will be shipped by default in 11.10, but I was wondering if there is a plugin or addon (out now) that will allow me to backup to my Ubuntu One account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need a plugin for that? If you want to, you can just make a new directory in your home, call it .backup_hostname, use it in Daja Dup and sync it? (Only the Ubuntu One-folder is synced between all computers by default)

Comment: That's the thing I'm trying to avoid. I have 4 computers synced and I'm looking to backup 6GB. My bandwidth will shudder in terror.